# Oracle Sql Query to rollup but get main column to display only once

Tags: sql, oracle

PREVIOUS DATA WHICH I USED

```
 TOWNSHIP             PCT      TOTAL
 -------------------- --- ----------
 Agat                 4          688
 Agat                 04A        611
 Agat                 04B        603
 Agat                           1902
 Piti                 3          441
 Piti                            441
 Yigo                 19         376
 Yigo                 19A        405
 Yigo                 19B        465
 Yigo                 19C        418
 Yigo                 19D        353
 Yigo                 19E        373
 Yigo                 19F        318
 Yigo                           2708
 Yona                 10         395
 Yona                 10A        424
 Yona                 10B        343
```

NEW DATA LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
with tab as 
(
select 'Hagatna' as township, '1' as pct, 373 as voters,'1---(A-Z)' as 
precinct_inc,'Guam Congress Building' as polling location, 'Anigua' as 
landmark from dual union all
select 'Hagatna',    '1',   373,  '1---(A-Z)',     'Guam Congress Building',                         
'Anigua' from dual union all
select 'Piti',       '3',   441,  '3---(A-Z)',     'Jose L.G. Rios Middle 
School Cafeteria',         'Nimitz Hill Estate'                   from dual 
union all
select 'Agat',       '4',   688,  '4---(A-D)',     'Marcial Sablan Elem. 
School Classrooms',         'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach'              from dual 
union all  
select 'Agat',       '04A', 611,  '4A-(E-P)',      'Marcial Sablan Elem. 
School Classrooms',         'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach'              from dual 
union all    
select 'Agat',       '04B', 603,  '4B-(Q-Z)',      'Marcial Sablan Elem. 
School Classrooms',         'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach'              from dual 
union all    
select 'Santa Rita', '5',   537   '5---(A-K)',     'Harry S. Truman Elem 
School Classrooms',         'Apra Hts., Naval Station, Santa Rosa' from dual 
union all    
select 'Santa Rita', '05A', 555   '5A-(L-Z)',      'Harry S. Truman Elem 
School Classrooms',         'Apra Hts., Naval Station, Santa Rosa' from dual 
union all    
select 'Umatac',     '6',   315   '6---(A-Z)',     'Umatac Mayors Office',                           
'n/a'                                  from dual union all
select 'Merizo',     '7',   501   '7---(A-K)',     'Merizo  Martyrs Memorial 
Elem School Cafeteria', 'n/a'                                  from dual 
union all
select 'Merizo',     '07A', 531   '7A-(L-Z)',      'Merizo  Martyrs Memorial 
Elem School Cafeteria', 'n/a'                                  from dual 
union all select 'Inarajan',   '8',   412   '8---(A-Fi)',    'Inarajan 
Middle School Classrooms',              'Malojloj'                             
from dual union all
select 'Inarajan',   '08A', 433   '8A-(Fj-Pa)',    'Inarajan Middle School 
Classrooms',              'Malojloj'                             from dual 
union all
select 'Inarajan',   '08B', 383   '8B-(Pb-Z)',     'Inarajan Middle School 
Classrooms',              'Malojloj'                             from dual 
union all
select 'Talofofo',   '9',   624   '9---(A-M)',     'Talofofo Elem.  School 
Classrooms',              'Babulao, Ipan'                        from dual 
union all
select 'Talofofo',   '09A', 589   '9A-(N-Z)',      'Talofofo Elem.  School 
Classrooms',               'Babulao, Ipan'                        from dual 
union all
select 'Yona',       '10',  395   '10--(A-E)',     'MU Lujan Elem.  School 
Cafeteria',               'Baza Gardens, Togcha'                 from dual 
union all  
select 'Yona',       '10A', 424   '10A-(F-P)',     'MU Lujan Elem.  School 
Cafeteria',               'Baza Gardens, Togcha'                 from dual 
union all
select 'Yona',       '10B', 343   '10B-(Q-Z)',     'MU Lujan Elem.  School 
Cafeteria',               'Baza Gardens, Togcha'                 from dual )
```

This is how my data looks like now i dont want to display TOWNSHIP column more than once how to achieve this in sql?

It should like below any idea on how to achieve this.

```
  TOWNSHIP             PCT      TOTAL
  -------------------- --- ----------
  Agat                 4          688
                       04A        611
                       04B        603
  Total                           1902

  MY QUERY:

 COL VILLAGE FOR A20
 SET PAGESIZE 50000
  set lines 154
  --grouping(district), grouping(pct)
 select NVL(DISTRICT,'')
 district, pct,
 sum(VOTERS) as TOTAL FROM 
 (SELECT distinct DISTRICT,
 PCT,
 COUNT(*) AS VOTERS
   FROM
  REG_TAB
 JOIN PCT_LOOKUP
 ON
 PCT=PERCINCT_MAP
 AND VILLAGE IN (UPPER(SUBSTR(DISTRICT,1,INSTR(DISTRICT,'/',1)-1)),UPPER( 
 SUBSTR(REPLACE(DISTRICT,'.',''),INSTR(DISTRICT,'/',1)+1,99))) GROUP BY   
 PCT,DISTRICT ORDER BY to_number(substr(PCT,1,length(PCT)- 
 nvl(length(replace(translate(PCT,'0123456789','0000000000'),'0','')),0))),
 substr(PCT,1+length(PCT)- 
 nvl(length(replace(translate(PCT,'0123456789','0000000000'),'0','')),0)) 
 NULLS FIRST) group by ROLLUP(district, pct) ;
```

I want to get like above table i tried rollup but that brings the column name but i dont want that column name to be displayed multiple times instead once is enough.

Just figuring out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

[ROLLUP, CUBE, GROUPING Functions and GROUPING SETS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) and the ROW_NUMBER() function?

```
with
  t as (
    select
      'Hagatna' as township,
      '1' as pct,
      373 as voters,
      '1---(A-Z)' as precinct_inc,
      'Guam Congress Building' as polling_location,
      'Anigua' as landmark from dual union all
    select
      'Hagatna', '1', 373, '1---(A-Z)', 'Guam Congress Building', 'Anigua'
    from dual union all
    select 'Piti', '3', 441, '3---(A-Z)',
      'Jose L.G. Rios Middle School Cafeteria',
      'Nimitz Hill Estate' from dual union all
    select 'Agat', '4', 688, '4---(A-D)',
      'Marcial Sablan Elem. School Classrooms',
      'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach' from dual union all
    select 'Agat', '04A', 611, '4A-(E-P)',
      'Marcial Sablan Elem. School Classrooms',
      'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach' from dual union all
    select 'Agat', '04B', 603, '4B-(Q-Z)',
      'Marcial Sablan Elem. School  Classrooms',
      'Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach'  from dual union all
    select 'Santa Rita', '5', 537, '5---(A-K)',
      'Harry S. Truman Elem School  Classrooms',
      'Apra Hts., Naval Station, Santa Rosa' from dual union all
    select 'Santa Rita', '05A',555, '5A-(L-Z)',
      'Harry S. Truman Elem School Classrooms',
      'Apra Hts., Naval Station, Santa Rosa' from dual union all
    select 'Umatac', '6', 315, '6---(A-Z)', 'Umatac Mayor''s Office', 'n/a'
    from dual union all
    select 'Merizo', '7', 501, '7---(A-K)',
       'Merizo Martyrs Memorial Elem School Cafeteria', 'n/a' from dual union all
    select 'Merizo',  '07A',531, '7A-(L-Z)',
      'Merizo Martyrs Memorial Elem School Cafeteria', 'n/a' from dual union all
    select 'Inarajan','8', 412, '8---(A-Fi)',
      'Inarajan Middle School Classrooms', 'Malojloj' from dual union all
    select 'Inarajan','08A',433, '8A-(Fj-Pa)',
      'Inarajan Middle School Classrooms', 'Malojloj' from dual union all
    select 'Inarajan','08B',383, '8B-(Pb-Z)',
      'Inarajan Middle School Classrooms', 'Malojloj' from dual union all
    select 'Talofofo','9',624, '9---(A-M)',
      'Talofofo Elem. School Classrooms', 'Babulao, Ipan' from dual union all
    select 'Talofofo','09A',589, '9A-(N-Z)',
      'Talofofo Elem. School Classrooms', 'Babulao, Ipan' from dual union all
    select 'Yona', '10', 395, '10--(A-E)',
      'MU Lujan Elem. School Cafeteria', 'Baza Gardens, Togcha' from dual union all
    select 'Yona', '10A', 424, '10A-(F-P)',
      'MU Lujan Elem.  School Cafeteria', 'Baza Gardens, Togcha' from dual union all
    select 'Yona', '10B', 343, '10B-(Q-Z)',
      'MU Lujan Elem. School Cafeteria', 'Baza Gardens, Togcha' from dual
  )
select
  case grouping(township)
    when 1 then 'Total'
    else case row_number() over (partition by township
                                 order by grouping(pct), precinct_inc)
           when 1 then township
           else case grouping(pct)
                  when 1 then township||'''s Total'
                  else ' '
                end
         end
  end as township,
  pct, precinct_inc,
  case row_number() over (partition by township
                          order by grouping(pct), precinct_inc)
    when 1 then polling_location
    else ' '
  end as polling_location,
  case row_number() over (partition by township
                          order by grouping(pct), precinct_inc)
    when 1 then landmark
    else ' '
  end as landmark,
  sum(voters)
from t
group by
  rollup(township, (township, pct, precinct_inc, polling_location, landmark))
order by grouping(t.township), t.township,
         grouping(t.pct), precinct_inc;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------------------+-----+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
|      TOWNSHIP      | PCT | PRECINCT_INC |               POLLING_LOCATION                |               LANDMARK               | SUM(VOTERS) |
+--------------------+-----+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
| Agat               | 4   | 4---(A-D)    | Marcial Sablan Elem. School Classrooms        | Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach              |         688 |
|                    | 04A | 4A-(E-P)     |                                               |                                      |         611 |
|                    | 04B | 4B-(Q-Z)     |                                               |                                      |         603 |
| Agat's Total       |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1902 |
| Hagatna            | 1   | 1---(A-Z)    | Guam Congress Building                        | Anigua                               |         746 |
| Hagatna's Total    |     |              |                                               |                                      |         746 |
| Inarajan           | 8   | 8---(A-Fi)   | Inarajan Middle School Classrooms             | Malojloj                             |         412 |
|                    | 08A | 8A-(Fj-Pa)   |                                               |                                      |         433 |
|                    | 08B | 8B-(Pb-Z)    |                                               |                                      |         383 |
| Inarajan's Total   |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1228 |
| Merizo             | 7   | 7---(A-K)    | Merizo Martyrs Memorial Elem School Cafeteria | n/a                                  |         501 |
|                    | 07A | 7A-(L-Z)     |                                               |                                      |         531 |
| Merizo's Total     |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1032 |
| Piti               | 3   | 3---(A-Z)    | Jose L.G. Rios Middle School Cafeteria        | Nimitz Hill Estate                   |         441 |
| Piti's Total       |     |              |                                               |                                      |         441 |
| Santa Rita         | 5   | 5---(A-K)    | Harry S. Truman Elem School  Classrooms       | Apra Hts., Naval Station, Santa Rosa |         537 |
|                    | 05A | 5A-(L-Z)     |                                               |                                      |         555 |
| Santa Rita's Total |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1092 |
| Talofofo           | 9   | 9---(A-M)    | Talofofo Elem. School Classrooms              | Babulao, Ipan                        |         624 |
|                    | 09A | 9A-(N-Z)     |                                               |                                      |         589 |
| Talofofo's Total   |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1213 |
| Umatac             | 6   | 6---(A-Z)    | Umatac Mayor's Office                         | n/a                                  |         315 |
| Umatac's Total     |     |              |                                               |                                      |         315 |
| Yona               | 10  | 10--(A-E)    | MU Lujan Elem. School Cafeteria               | Baza Gardens, Togcha                 |         395 |
|                    | 10A | 10A-(F-P)    |                                               |                                      |         424 |
|                    | 10B | 10B-(Q-Z)    |                                               |                                      |         343 |
| Yona's Total       |     |              |                                               |                                      |        1162 |
| Total              |     |              |                                               |                                      |        9131 |
+--------------------+-----+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7bdefc59684d1d2ea497452235cb4044).

Comment: is it possible to avoid Township column value being printed more than once? Say for example 'Agat' should come only once instead of 4 times

Comment: @vinodh, i corrected my answer. But why do not format  on the client side?

Comment: its working thanks but if want to sort by PCT column it just goes for toss and total goes at the bottom. How to sort in this case.

Comment: thanks Andrei actually i have 2 more columns which landmark and sitename sample data is like (Column Landmark -->Agat and Column SiteName -> Mt.Lamlam, Finile Beach ) how can i get those values also once just by grouping should work i beilve i will give it a try with that db<>fiddle once. Thanks for posting your answers.

Comment: i have uploaded sample data with all columns with this i am trying to achieve the same which you previously sent by my PCT column goes for a toss.

Comment: @vinodh, check new answer.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for quick response here i want to sort by PRECINCT_INC column so that 1--(A-Z) comes first and then others seems bit complicated using PRECINCT_INC column. Also the landmark and polling_site repeated more than once i want like once once per group.

Comment: @vinodh, I have prepared a new answer that may be suitable for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks very much @Andrei that's a lot of learning from you today. I guess sorting by using PCT column won't work i guess it's very tricky part. I will see adding some prequel to district based on PCT and sort to get it ordered by PCT column.

Comment: i tried Andrei but it says i dont have 15 reputation to set this answer is helpful :(.

Comment: @vinodh, nevermind. Good luck in raising your reputation :)